# How to find all the schema which has one schema as reference in schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Say I have schema called "address" defined.
This schema is referenced in employee, person, employer, customer, etc ...

So, I should see the list of schema that are referencing this schema

Is there any API or cURL to fetch all the schemas which has the reference of this schema?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer to your question in the API interface documentation.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#schemas

Comment: There's not an API for this. You'd need to loop over all subjects and all versions for each subject

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the _schemas topic directly, and parse its content. It's just JSON.

If you want to search the data, maybe dump into system like Opensearch or Mongo using Kafka Connect

Comment: Looks like we have this API for fetching references
`subjects/topic/versions/2/referencedby` but we need to fetch it for all the versions individually.

Comment: Sure, or you can consume the topic, and manually extract the same information